# Does Archon of Coronation prevent life loss in two-headed giant if my teammate is the defending player?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm the monarch, with an [Archon of Coronation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=497529) on the board. My teammate gets attacked with a [Changeling Outcast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=567560). Do we lose life?

Archon of Coronation says  "...damage doesn't cause you to lose life", is that implied to mean that "...damage [you take] doesn't cause you to lose life"? Because my teammate getting hit seems like it *is damage that would cause me to lose life*. I have a feeling this doesn't work this way, but I'm not sure. Relevant sections from the comprehensive rules would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, Archon of Coronation prevents life loss to your whole team.**

In 2HG, your life total is shared with your teammate. If your teammate would lose life from taking damage, then so would you, and Archon prevents that from happening.

> 810.9h If an effect says that a player can’t lose life, no player on that player’s team can lose life or pay any amount of life other than 0.

Note, however, that the wording is important here. If the Archon were to "prevent damage" instead of preventing life loss, only you would be protected from that damage and damage to your teammate would still cause your team to lose life.

Comment: And in a Commander game, the wording means it doesn't keep you from losing from Commander damage.

Comment: Not sure about this. This doesn't say you can't lose life, it says damage doesn't cause you to lose life. While they may be similar and have a similar effect, they aren't the same thing. As a judge I would probably rule the archon doesn't actually protect your teammate since its a damage modification affect only applies to one player on the team, particularly since the monarch is also only on one player on the team.

Comment: @Andrew This is what I discussed in my 2nd paragraph. See the 4-part damage sequence in 120.4. Archon does not modify the damage itself (step 2) as you assert. It modifies one of the possible damage *results* (step 3), specifically life loss. Damage still happens in full, and all damage results except life loss also happen in full.